# RetailInfo class is missing in Windows::System::Profile namespace

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

I have UWP app and I need to include Retail Mode experience in it.

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/retail-demo-experience) I need to use

> IsDemoModeEnabled property in the RetailInfo utility class, which is
>   part of the Windows.System.Profile namespace in the Windows 10 SDK

I installed Visual Studio 2017 v 15.4.4 with all Windows 10 SDKs.

There is no RetailInfo class neither in Windows.System.Profile (C# project) nor in Windows::System::Profile namespace (C++/CX project).

What should I install in order to get RetailInfo class in Windows::System::Profile ?

Comment: Check the contract information [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Profile.RetailInfo). You need to add a reference either to the desktop extension or the mobile extension.

Comment: Hi, Raymond! Thank you. I added more details of how to add reference and submitted as answer. Kind regards, Julia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**References -> Add Reference -> Universal Windows -> Extensions -> Windows Mobile Extensions for UWP (Version 10.0.10240.0)** did the trick.

[How to add reference to Windows Mobile Extensions for UWP in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7ORB.png)

Comment: Actually Raymond Chen shared the direction for your case. Can you clarify the contract info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/ in your answer and then mark it so that it will be clear to other members?

Comment: Hi, Barry. I added more details to the answer, hopefully it's more clear now :) Kind regards